# why background image is taking radius and not fit to div

Tags: html, css, background-image

Because the image's width and height are appropriate for the snippet, it is shown correctly. The picture I'm adding doesn't fit in the div because it's for mobile devices.

[image]

```css
 .story-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .desert-story {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1664575262619-b28fef7a40a4?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    position: relative;

  }

  .story-description {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 321px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: radial-gradient(76.31% 191.89% at 13.43% 22.19%, rgba(226, 228, 231, 0.8) 0%, rgba(228, 228, 229, 0.368) 100%);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    padding: 23px;
  }
```

```html
   <div class="story-content">
        <div class="desert-story">
          <div class="story-description">
            <p>
              We saw a gap between what people need and what banks offer. It
              means millions of us aren't getting the banking experience we
              deserve for different reasons.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: What image are you referring to.  The image is not in the CSS selection setting radius, etc.  And it is not taking the radius. BTW you will get a better image if you delete the '&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60' from above.

Comment: @petern0691 i fixed it by giving background-attachment and background size